# Read elements of dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dynamic

I have a form where the user can add any number of fields. They can also remove these fields.

I would like to be able to have an array which keeps tracks of the values in the form - *preferably without the use of a submit button.* i.e. this array is updated whenever the user changes a value in the form.

However, I do not know how to do that - so I attempted to make one with the use of a submit button. However, it only reads the final form entry and not all of the entries.

This is my attempt here:

```
document.querySelector('form.data').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
//prevent the normal submission of the form
e.preventDefault();
var values = {};
$.each($('form.data').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
values[field.name] = field.value;
});

console.info(values);    

});
```

JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/tomi2/4cqtpefm/4/

Full Code:

HTML:

```
    <form role="form" action="/wohoo" method="POST" class="data">
      <label>Variable 1, Variable 2</label>
        <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
          <div class="multi-fields">
            <div class="multi-field">
              <input type="text" name="Var1[]">
              <input type="text" name="Var2[]">
              <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
        <button type="submit"> Submit </button>

      </div>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
    $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
        $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
    });
    $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
        if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
            $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
    });
});

document.querySelector('form.data').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    //prevent the normal submission of the form
    e.preventDefault();

    var values = {};
    $.each($('form.data').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
    values[field.name] = field.value;
});

    console.info(values);    



});
```

Comment: the issue that you have is because when you clone row input fields have the same name.. I can make you example with generated names, will that be fine for you?

Comment: That would be fine - potentially even more helpful - but if it generates the name, I would still like to be able to do operations with all the inputs. I.e. be able to sum up all the inputted data, but I wouldn't know how to do this if they weren't in a big array.

Comment: take a look @answer I posted,, that gives you all results with your variable as array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here, try this.. this will give you full results on submit..

```js
var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields');
$(".add-field").on( 'click', function(e) {
  $('.multi-field:first-child',       $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
});
$('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
  if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
    $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
});


$('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(el) {
  el.preventDefault();
  alert( JSON.stringify( $('form').serializeArray() ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <form role="form" action="/wohoo" method="POST" class="data">
      <label>Variable 1, Variable 2</label>
        <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
          <div class="multi-fields">
            <div class="multi-field">
              <input type="text" name="Var1[]">
              <input type="text" name="Var2[]">
              <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
        <button type="submit"> Submit </button>

      </div>
    </form>
```